# From Django 1.11 onwards, context passed in render method should be a dictionary rather than a Context object. Then how context.render_context works?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

render() in django.shortcuts calls render_to_string method of loader module, which calls render method of Template class by creating a Template object. Till now, context is a dictionary.
Inside render method in Template class,

```
context.render_context.push_state(self):
```

How does this works? Because render_context is an attribute of Context class which gets assigned a RenderContext object. So, how context being not an instance of Context class can access its attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

context is being setup when calling Template [`render`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cfacd69ab81c37564799a7b8a0a765e3c1f40941/django/template/backends/django.py#L56) method

```
context = make_context(
    context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape
)
```

[`make_context`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/cfacd69ab81c37564799a7b8a0a765e3c1f40941/django/template/context.py#L281)

Comment: But this render_to_string method present in Engine class, doesn't get called. Rather the render_to_string method present in loader module gets called as inside render method in shortcuts the render_to_string method is being called like this : content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

Comment: read your question wrong but basically there is always step from engine

Comment: Can you explain how the entire function calls take place. So render method in shortcuts calls render_to_string in loaders, which in turn calls get_template in loaders assuming its a single template_name which again calls get_template in Engine class. The get_template present in Engine class returns `template = Template(template, origin, template_name, engine=self)` an object of the Template class present in  django/template/base.py. So when does the Template class present in django/template/backends/django.py is instantiated so as to call the render having make_context method.

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/10c7c7320baf1c655fcb91202169d77725c9c4bd/django/template/loader.py#L62

Comment: But that render call is the call to Template class in django\template\base.py. But the render method you mentioned in your answer is the one present in django\template\backends\django.py. Also, why I am thinking this because of this [https://github.com/django/django/blob/10c7c7320baf1c655fcb91202169d77725c9c4bd/django/template/engine.py#L178]

Comment: it seems you have confused engines import ( EngineHandler instance ) with Engine class, EngineHandler will instantiate engine class ( one from TEMPLATES setting e.g.: django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates )

Comment: Got it need to go through the docs again.

Comment: What does this line implies import  . from engines. Does this means importing Engine Handler instance?

Comment: yes https://github.com/django/django/blob/10c7c7320baf1c655fcb91202169d77725c9c4bd/django/template/__init__.py#L47